# Router hangs on outbound round trip back to internal server

Tags: router

If I try to access my staging server from inside my network the http request will hang if data being transfered is over a kilobyte or so.

I'm using an airlink 101, my staging server has its own domain name/IP addres, but if I access the staging server through the router a guaranteed hang. I can ping the server using its domain name/IP address but that's about it

Any ideas on what may be going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try running other service other than http. Like ftp. Can you succesfully use ftp services? If yes, then problem with http server. If no, then problem with network. This should help in narrowing possible causes.

1500 MTU is standard and should not cause any problems. But all the devices in middle, not just end hosts should support this MTU.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that may be related to MTU sizes. This can sometimes happen if you've blocked ICMP messages (except ping), since [path MTU discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_discovery) uses ICMP "fragmentation needed" messages to negotiate the maximum MTU size.

Answer (score 0):

Too new here to comment so....
A follow up question my MTU is 1500, this good or bad?

I don't see anything blocking ICMP, any place in particular to look?